# why is the operator undefined when inserting []?

Tags: java, arrays, double

I don't know how to resolve this.
Why does it say the operator is undefined and how do I resolve this?

My guess is that it's due to the brackets [ and ] but when removing them, it says that it can't convert int to double.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double value1 = 5.0;
    double[] valuearray = {1,2,3};
    int p = 2;

System.out.print("The L" + p + "-distance between: " + value1 + " and " + valuearray + " = " + getLpDistance(value1, valuearray, p));

  }
public static Double getLpDistance(double value1, double[] valuearray, int p) {
    int d = 1;
    double tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
      tmp += Math.pow(Math.abs(value1 - valuearray), p);
    }
    return Math.pow(tmp, 1.0 / p);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You have set the value of d =1, the loop will run only once. Second, to use your valuearray, you have to use it like valuearray[i]. Add more details in your question for more help.

Comment: I am trying to get the distance between an every element of an array and a specific value. Just realised that my code is bullshit...

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is correct: You cannot subtract an Array of Doubles (`valuearray`) from a Double (`value1`).

To return the subtraction of every single element of `valuearray`, you would have to do it like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++) {
  tmp += Math.pow(Math.abs(value1 - valuearray[i]), p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to measure the distance, your code looks quite close. I have done a few changes in the code. Danger point is when you will set p = 0, the code will break. Assuming you have to deal that as a special case.

Below code for your reference. I have added comments for your information.

```
public class LPDistance {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double value1 = 5.0;
    double[] valuearray = {1,2,3};
    //when you have to deal with p = 0, you have to add some conditions in your code to deal with that...
    int p = 2;
    System.out.print("The L" + p + "-distance between: " + value1 + " and " + printArray(valuearray) + " = " + getLpDistance(value1, valuearray, p));

  }
private static String printArray(double[] valuearray) {
    //utility function to print an array
    String arrayPrint = "[ ";
    for(int i=0;i<valuearray.length-1;i++)
        arrayPrint+=valuearray[i]+", ";
    arrayPrint+=valuearray[valuearray.length-1]+" ]";
    return arrayPrint;
}
public static Double getLpDistance(double value1, double[] valuearray, int p) {

    //  int d = 1; don't need to set this if you want to go through all the array elements
    double tmp = 0;
    //updated the loop parameters to traverse through the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < valuearray.length; i++) {
      tmp += Math.pow(Math.abs(value1 - valuearray[i]), 2); // if it is distance, power will be always 2
    }
    //if you will pass p=0, below code will fail.
    return Math.pow(tmp, 1.0 / p);
}

}
```